# Show the current occurrence for a searched term as a number out of the total of all occurrences of that term through a file for Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

For example I have this document that in Notepad++ it takes only one line, where the word "calculator" has 112 occurences (see the 2 red rectangles):
[image]

, but when I go ahead to use "Find next" I'd also like to see the current occurrence of the word "calculator".

For example when I hit "Find next" I'd like for the first occurrence of "calculator" to show up as 1/112 while it gets highlighted. Next time I hit "Find next" it should show up as 2/112 and highlight the next occurrence of "calculator".

I've noticed Chrome does it exactly how I want it:
[image]

Unfortunately "Find All in Current Document" only works properly, to suit my case in a somewhat similar manner, if the text would be split into multiple lines, unlike my case, where it takes only 1 line.

How to achive this without having to modify the original text (eg: no splitting into multiple lines) or without having to use a different program other than Notepad++?

Would the Python Script plugin be helpful in this case?
Or are there any plugins that could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Python script could probably do that, but I can't help with this.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna wait for more answers, maybe someone has some experience knowing if it would be definitely possible to make it work with Python Script. If not, I'm gonna be looking it up thoroughly to see what I get, perhaps I'm gonna make it work.

Comment: There's certainly a workaround of adding the number of occurence with find/replace functionality and replacing it back later, but it's clunky as you can't really add text dynamically with that method.

Comment: I see. Thank you!